# string.contains() doesn't exist while working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a code like:

```
var valid = viewName.contains('/');
```

which works fine in firefox browser. But in chrome it is `undefined`. Why is that so? Is it true that chrome has not such a method for string?

Is it OK to use `indexOf` instead of `contains`, is it supported in all browsers?

Comment: Is the missing quote a typo?

Comment: its defined in my chrome, which is 28.0.1500.71, but according to MDN it is not supported so maybe they just added it. As for indexOf its been around for quite awhile so it can be used

Comment: @LightStyle yep, I've just corrected it.

Comment: This is now named `.includes` per the ES6 Harmony Proposal.

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer is now outdated and incorrect. See my answer just beneath! Happy coding.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[image: Browser compatibility of String.contains()]

`String.indexOf()` is what I use and it will work fine.

```
  var strIndex = viewName.indexOf('/');
  if(strIndex == -1) {
     //string not found
  } else {
    //string found
  }
```

But, just in case you want to have a `contains()` function, you can add it to `String` as below:

```
 if(!('contains' in String.prototype)) {
       String.prototype.contains = function(str, startIndex) {
                return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
       };
 }

var valid = viewName.contains('/');
if(valid) {
  //string found
} else {
  //string not found
}
```

Comment: Your polyfill is broken - the specification of contains is different. See MDN.

Comment: Just an FYI: The ES6 Draft Standard changed `.contains()` to be named `.includes()`  `.contains()` will be removed from Firefox eventually and replaced with the standard `.includes`.  Currently Chrome provides `.includes`.

Comment: Using polyfill to provide functionality which already exists natively in the browser is, IMO, bad practise. Also, this answer is now out of date. Perhaps the author could update it?

Comment: at the time the answer was added, contains was not natively supported in all browsers

Answer (score 9):

Support for this, in Firefox and Chrome too, is now disabled by default. If you land here looking for an up to date answer, you can view the reason why, and the new method name (which is `String.includes`) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Try:

`yourString.includes('searchString')`

Answer (score 2):

.contains was entirely removed in FireFox 48 as the documentation, currently last updated on 22.07.2016, reveals. The function .includes does what .contains did before, though.

Benefits: .includes is also supported by Chrome.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes for reference.

I was going to post this as comment but unregistered people can only write full answers. (facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

The `contains` method of strings was [first added to V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2796), then [included in Chrome](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=214713&view=revision) after [version 30.0.1583.0](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/VERSION?pathrev=214713), but it is disabled by default. This feature **is only available** if you enable "experimental JavaScript features" at `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony`.