# JavaScript is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I am new in javaScript.

I have one textbox that i want to use like timepicker.

when I run application with using Firefox working fine but not woking in crome and any other browser

Javascript Code:-

```
$("#MainContent_txtShipFrom").keyup(function () {
                $('#MainContent_txtShipFrom').blur(function () {
                    var validTime = $(this).val().match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d)$/);
                    if (!validTime) {
                        if ($(this).val() == '')
                            $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
                        else
                            $(this).css('background', '#FF0055');
                    } else {
                        $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
                    }
                });

                var Value = $("#MainContent_txtShipFrom").val();

                if (Value.length > 1 && Value.length < 3) {
                    if (Value.contains(':')) {
                        $("#MainContent_txtShipFrom").val("0" + Value);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#MainContent_txtShipFrom").val(Value + ":");
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Problem**

ValidTime script is working perfect but  Add " `:` " script is not working in crome

Comment: on each keyup you are setting an additional onblur event listener

Comment: What happens when you try to debug your script (like put breakpoints/look at console)?

Comment: also instead of `Value.length > 1 && Value.length < 3` you could just do `Value.length == 2`

Comment: when i debug with crome is show me on  Value.contains(':') :- Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: possible duplicate of [string.contains() doesn't exist while working in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196337/string-contains-doesnt-exist-while-working-in-chrome)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $("#MainContent_txtShipFrom").keyup(function () {
                $('#MainContent_txtShipFrom').blur(function () {
                    var validTime = $(this).val().match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d)$/);
                    if (!validTime) {
                        if ($(this).val() == '')
                            $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
                        else
                            $(this).css('background', '#FF0055');
                    } else {
                        $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
                    }
                });
                var Value = $("#MainContent_txtShipFrom").val();
                if (Value.length == 2) {
                    $("#MainContent_txtShipFrom").val(Value + ":");
                }
            });


            $("#MainContent_txtShipTo").keyup(function () {
                $('#MainContent_txtShipTo').blur(function () {
                    var validTime = $(this).val().match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d)$/);
                    if (!validTime) {
                        if ($(this).val() == '')
                            $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
                        else
                            $(this).css('background', '#FF0055');
                    } else {
                        $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
                    }

                });

                var Value = $("#MainContent_txtShipTo").val();
                if (Value.length == 2) {
                    $("#MainContent_txtShipTo").val(Value + ":");
                }
            });
```