# Is String.contains a standard function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, standard-library, ecmascript-harmony

Recently I was writing logic in JavaScript and I wrote something like this

```js
var str="hello world";

if(str.contains("w"))
    //do something
else
   //do anotherthing
```

I thought it  was working fine until I ran the page in Chrome. In Chrome I'm getting an error of `contains is not a function`.

Although I got rid of this by modifying the logic as

```js
var str="hello world";
if(str.indexOf("w")!=-1)
    //do something
else
   //do another thing
```

is `contains` not a standard ECMAScript function? I'm able to see `contains` through intellisense  in Firefox but not in Chrome.

While testing these in different browsers I noticed in the console that

`String.subString/indexOf  //not showing in chrome but works in Firefox`

instead  `str.substring/indexOf` works in chrome

Aren't these methods are part of standard `String` object?

Comment: `.includes` is the standard name of the method. `.contains` was preferred, but it broke websites because a once popular library (Mootools) had defined the string's `.contains` method with different semantics.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 1):

It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196337/string-contains-doesnt-exist-while-working-in-chrome). String.prototype.contains is not a part of EsmaScript 5.1, which is currently releases.

Comment: As of June, 2015, [*ECMAScript ed 6*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) is the current standard. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196337/string-contains-doesnt-exist-while-working-in-chrome/36793312#36793312) question.

I will repost the answer here for convenience.

Support for this, in Firefox and Chrome too, is now disabled by default. If you land here looking for an up to date answer, you can view the reason why, and the new method name (which is String.includes) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Try:

yourString.includes('searchString')

Answer (score 0):

`.contains()` is not part of the standard string objects